# React and Typescript: Convention for classes when no props are being passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm wondering what's the proper way of specifying that a React component has no props in Typescript.

If I have a component I can specify what props and state has with two interfaces:

```
interface MyProps {
  text: string
}

interface MyState {
  count: number
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
  ...
}
```

So, if my component has no props, should I use `void`, `undefined` or `{}`?

Comment: I don't think that there's a "proper way" to do it, but I usually use `void` when a component has no props (or no state), s it's [written in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void): `the absence of having any type at all`

Comment: `{}` is preferable from a type system perspective. `undefined` is simply inaccurate and `void` makes no sense. @NitzanTomer doesn't no props map to the concept of the empty set rather than no set at all?

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @AluanHaddad I guess that it depends what you're trying to convey. When a component doesn't have any props I usually prefer to look at it as a component that has no notion of props, instead of a component that has no props.  I'd use `{}` when there's inheritance and the parent class doesn't need any props.  But, it's a personal preference.

Comment: @NitzanTomer thank you for explaining, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact (almost) question is answered in the announcement for [Typescript 2.3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/04/27/announcing-typescript-2-3/).

> However, much of the time, state is never used in a component. In those cases, we can just write the type as object or {}, but we have to do so explicitly:
>
> ```
> class FooComponent extends React.Component<FooProps, object> {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

So in your cases, you would just reverse the usage of `object` for the props param instead of the state param.